# How can I center three tables in a div?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with a CSS problem. I have three tables and I need them to center in a div. I have tried floating, text-align:center and anything else came in mind but I just cannot make it work.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:91%;">
[one_third]
<table>
<tr>
<td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/clock.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;">55'</td> 
</tr>
</table>
[/one_third]

[one_third]
<table>
<tr>
<td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/stats.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;">4-5</td> 
</tr>
</table>
[/one_third]

[one_third_last]
<table>
<tr>
<td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/zigaria2.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;">500</td> 
</tr>
</table>
[/one_third_last]
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.one_third {
position: relative;
margin-right: 4%;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
margin-bottom: 0;
width: 30.66%;
}

.last {
margin-right: 0!important;
clear: right;
}
```

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: stop using [Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design) to do the layout, you can use css, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) can help you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @EmilioGort. I haven't used Bootstrap before, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Is the image - how you want it ?

Comment: Table is the best way to go - I don't think you are doing it right though. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Ani I need the images with their text below to come closer and be centered to the photo above.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve  http://jsfiddle.net/ZssZw/

Comment: what is `[/one_third] [one_third]`

Comment: @ani how is table the best way? oh yes 15 years ago

Comment: @Ani It's a shortcode included in the theme I am using. The change you've made resolved the problem with the margins between them. The other thing I was trying to achieve is to center them. Right now there are left aligned.

Comment: @Ani Actually that was easy after your fix. I just had to add 'margin: 0 auto;' to the table.
Would you like to post it as a proper answer?

Comment: @EmilioGort I hear you. Tables are not the best approach in 2013 I just couldn't find another way to put everything in place. I'll definitely check your suggestion.

Comment: Ok done. Actually Tables are pretty good and are easy to implement with responsive design too.

Comment: @ani yes...to show tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZssZw/

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:91%;">

 <table>
    <tr>
       <td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/clock.png"/></td>
       <td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/stats.png"/></td>
       <td><img height="35" width="32" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/zigaria2.png"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align:center;">55'</td> 

       <td style="text-align:center;">4-5</td> 
       <td style="text-align:center;">500</td> 
     </tr>


     </table>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why tables are being used.  Bootstrap was mentioned, and is the right idea -- Maybe a bit of overkill, you just need a bit of the grid.  Stealing some from Bootstrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/U9Reg/

```
<style>
        div {
        display: block;
        }
        p {
        text-align: center;
        }
        .row {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px
}

.col-md-4 {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 1px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
}

.centerPix {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
height: 65px;
width: 65px;
}</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="centerPix" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/clock.png"/><p>Here is some text.</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="centerPix" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/stats.png"/>
<p>Here is some text</p></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="centerPix" src="http://alimos.topgreekgyms.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/zigaria2.png"/>
<p>Here is some text.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Travtext how do I center them through in this approach. Their floating to the left in your example.

Comment: They're centered -- I just used the 'medium' size from bootstrap's responsive classes and the default view is a little narrow, so one of them kicks down to the next row as-is.  Expand the view.  Also try: http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html